# CakePHP :: afterFind() with non-primary model

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

In this application, I have a Rental model which is central to the application.  Rentals are associated with a Client, a Location, and a piece of Equipment.  In almost all cases, I want to 'clean' the results, leaving only Rentals that are currently active.  However, I don't want to do that in all cases, so what is the best methodology for flagging this?

My current thought is to add a Model variable (`$cleanRentals = true`), and set that flag to false when necessary, and to check the variable in `afterFind()`.

Answer (score 0):

Protecting / cleaning data like this on associated models in Cake shows where Cake's model system is lacking. It gets messy.

But I would consider creating a custom finder, something like

```
$this->Rental->findActive();
```

Then you could just use that when you want to get only the active rentals.

See more:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types

Comment: It appears that the code that I have now in the Rental `afterFind` method isn't even being fired - I have debug log-writes that aren't being written.

Comment: Yeah, it can be difficult to do this sort of thing with Cake. Possibly this is still a problem: http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/callbacks_not_triggered_for_associated_models_when_using_saveall